# Python - Can I modify a method in runtime?

Tags: python

Is it possible to modify a method in runtime?
Let's say I have a class `A` that has a method `func1(some_param)`.
Is it possible to modify this `func1(some_param)` method and let's say add a line `print('HelloWorld')` in the beginning?

I had some experiments with overriding this method by accessing it like this - `A.func1` but got stuck in the stage of inserting a line into it.

Here is the example class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_field):
        self.some_field = some_field
        
    def func1(self, param):
        self.some_field = param
```

And in runtime I want to achieve this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_field):
        self.some_field = some_field
        
    def func1(self, param):
        print('HelloWorld')
        self.some_field = param
```

Comment: Why do you not just write the second code from the beginning?

Comment: Do you need to _modify_ the method?  Could you just create a class `B` that _extends_ `A` and overrides the `func1` method (calling the parent method if need be)?

Comment: This sounds like maybe you need a decorator...

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/monkey-patching-in-python-dynamic-behavior/

But seriously, don't do it unless you really need to.

Comment: Thank you all
mkrieger1 I ran into this problem during a coding class I'm taking, so it's indeed easier but  it's against the task definition :)
RocketHazmat It's good idea I had but same as the previous comment, also against the task definition, I need to preserve the original class, just to modify it

Comment: Thank you Andrew, i'll give it a try.

Frank, the one thing I'm missing is how can I define a function in runtime? I got to this I mean how can I in runtime take the original function and define a new one based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing to do is insert line before or after you can use decorator, pass parameter to the decorator.
see this [article](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/#simple-decorators).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Python is very dynamic in that sense

Code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, some_field):
        self.some_field = some_field
        
    def func1(self, param):
        self.some_field = param

def func2(self, param):
    print('HelloWorld')
    self.some_field = param        

def func1(self, param):
    print('stand alone func')
    self.some_field = param        
    
a = A('init')
a.func1('for func1')
A.func2 = func2
a.func2('for func2')

A.func1 = func1     # you know this is not good programming practice
a.func1('for new func1')
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
stand alone func
```